# Asp.net membership password format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

i have application that uses asp.net membership. Unfortunately users password are stored using PasswordFormat clear. I want to change password to hashed format without asking user to setting theirs again. Another restriction is that UserId in Membership table can't be changed. Does anyone have any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt the passwords by configuring the membership provider setting & keys in web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
<providers>
<add
name="SqlProvider"
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
connectionStringName="SqlServices"
enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
enablePasswordReset="true"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
passwordFormat="Hashed"
minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^([1-zA-Z0-1@.\s]{1,255})$"
applicationName="NitinJS" />
</providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: But i need to have passwordformat hashed not encypt. I need to get salt and hashed password instead of clear password.

Answer (score 2):

In your web.config go to

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
     <clear/>
     <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
          type="MyProviders.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"  
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"             
          passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="4"
          passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"             
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true" />
   </providers>
 </membership>
```

And there's a "key generator" snippet in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) article, run it twice and shove them in your web.config as:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey  
    validationKey="<blah>"           
    decryptionKey="<blah>"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
    />
</system.web>
```